# how to to show and dismiss alertDilog Globally when ever receiver receive in android

Tags: android

```
 BroadcastReceiver updateBooleanBroadCastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {   
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (intent.getBooleanExtra("action", true)) {
                checkGPS();
                   } else {
                checkGPS();

                }
        }
    };

 private void checkGPS(){
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000L,1.0f, this);
        boolean isGPS = locationManager.isProviderEnabled (LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        if(isGPS){

        }else{

           Utils.displayPromptForEnablingGPS(true,MainActivity.this);

        }
    }
```

This is my Alert :

```
 public static void
    displayPromptForEnablingGPS(boolean a,
                                final Activity activity) {
        final AlertDialog.Builder builder =
                new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
        final String action = Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS;
        final String message = "Enable either GPS or any other location"
                + " service to find current location.  Click OK to go to"
                + " location services settings to let you do so.";

        builder.setMessage(message).setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("OK",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface d, int id) {
                                activity.startActivityForResult(new Intent(action),1);
                                d.dismiss();
                            }
                        })
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                       new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface d, int id) {

                                activity.finish();

                            }
                        });


            builder.create().show();

    }
```

I want to  Hide Alertdilog when location  On and when i  want to hide or dismiss when Location Off from Notification Manger Location i am able to receive event on receive method when we off and On Location Manger location when i off location from Location manger then i am able to show Alert But i am unable to disable Alert when i On Location plz help me  how i will acchive this please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

You can display your dialog in onrecieve method

```
private void displayAlert()
{
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?").setCancelable(
        false).setPositiveButton("Yes",
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        }).setNegativeButton("No",
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
}

private final BroadcastReceiver mReceivedSMSReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();

        if (ACTION.equals(action)) 
        {
            //your SMS processing code
            displayAlert();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But its not Hide when i on Location it show alert when location off it But when i On Location its not Hide @raj

Comment: yes and when On it should automatic hide i dont want to click any thing

Answer (score 0):

ok then you dont need broadcast reciever for that

you can do this in your activity on resume method

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {

    super.onResume();
    checkGPS();
} 

private void checkGPS(){
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000L,1.0f, this);
        boolean isGPS = locationManager.isProviderEnabled (LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        if(isGPS){

        }else{

           Utils.displayPromptForEnablingGPS(true,MainActivity.this);

        }
    }
```

Comment: Same issue i am unable to hide AlertDiolg when i On Location